# Remove duplicates where content_id and ip_address are the same In python django module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've got some code setup to count page clicks, the data is stored in ObjectViewed model every time a page is clicked. 
I'm currently counting how many times each page has been clicked but I would like to make it unique page clicks, so only show 1 click per page, per IP.

I'm attempting to filter out where ip_address and content_object appear together ina row, more than once.

```py
class ObjectViewed(models.Model):
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

#where these are together i want to only count once below
    content_object  = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ip_address      = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)


def analytics(request):
    objects = ObjectViewed.objects.all()
    q = NewsPost.objects.values('id').distinct()
    dict = {}

    for object in q:
        dict.update({list(object.values())[0]: 0})
        count = ObjectViewed.objects.values('object_id').annotate(c=Count('object_id')).order_by('-c')
```

Tried a few things, but new to python and django so I'm not quite sure what the best way is. 
Any help/guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you make things too hard here, and you probably do too much work yourself.

You can count the number of *distinct* `ip_address`es, with the `distinct=True` parameter of the [**`Count`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8), like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

ObjectViewed.objects.values('object_id', 'content_type').annotate(
    c=Count('ip_address', distinct=True)
).order_by('-c')
```

We can use that to effectively order our `NewsPost`s like:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models import Count

views = dict(ObjectViewed.objects.filter(
    content_type=get_object_for_this_type(NewsPost)
).values_list('object_id').annotate(
    c=Count('ip_address', distinct=True)
).order_by('object_id'))
```

then we can order the elements at the Django/Python level like:

```
my_newsposts = sorted(NewsPost.objects.all(), key=views.get, reverse=True)
```

We here thus first filter to only retrieve the *distinct* views on `NewsPost` objects, we put these in a dictionary named `views`, then we sort the `NewsPost` objects with that views in reversed order.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I knew there were better ways, just not sure exactly what was best so stuck to what I could understand.I do however get a error "Exception Value: name 'get_object_for_this_type' is not defined" but I get the principle of what is happening so I'll have a go at fixing it. I did add the import so that shouldn't be the issue.